# Update of the variable by constant in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The community helped me in developing this code

```
library(shiny)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame(N = numeric(0), A = numeric(0), C = numeric(0))

  newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{
    gr <- 10 + input$n
    newLine <- isolate(c(input$n, input$nr1, gr))
    values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$n, input$nr1, gr)
  })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("nr1", "Give a number: ",  min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step = 2),
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200, step = 10),
      actionButton("update", "Update Table"))),
    column(6, tableOutput("table1"))
  )
))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And I come to a new problem with that.

Now, I'd  like that the app do like this: on click on the update, the variable `A` should always add a 5 i.e. if I have starting value of 5 than on the next click it should be 10 than 15, 20 etc?
Now when I click update the same number appears continously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Also you dont need the `isolate` in there.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("nr1", "Give a number:",  min = 1, max = 100, value = 1, step = 1),
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200, step = 10),
      actionButton("update", "Update Table"))),
    column(6, tableOutput("table1"))
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame(N = numeric(0), A = numeric(0), C = numeric(0))

  newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{

    if(!is.null(input$nr1) & is.null(values$A)){
      values$A <- input$nr1
    }
    if(nrow(values$df) > 0){
      values$A <- values$A + 5
    }  
    gr <- 10 + input$n
    values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$n, values$A, gr)
  })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I removed `input$nr1 == 5 &` and I got what I wanted, Thanks @PorkChop

Comment: I wasnt 100% clear what you wanted originally so I did my best :)